# Manipulating nav menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a JavaScript beginner trying to solve 3 problems:

**1.** Upon clicking the parent `<li>`, the proper `<sub>` child's content doesn't appear. Notice that for each `<li>` category, i.e. "colors, shapes, sizes" there is an appropriate constituent child `<sub>` category. i.e. "green, circle, large"; however, upon clicking the the `<li>`, "large" appears as the content for each `<sub>` tag. How do I display the corresponding content upon clicking a given `<li>`?

**2.** My current code only toggles-off the previous click's content upon clicking the given `<li>` a second time. I'd like to not only toggle-off the li's display upon its second click, but also toggle-off the li's display upon clicking a different `<li>` whilst concurrently displaying the newly-clicked li's content.

**3.** I'm trying to smoothly transition (slide) the `<sub>` content out from behind the `<ul>`. I've tried doing so using the "transition" property but to no avail; upon clicking an `<li>` element, the `<sub>` just appears, but I'd like it to slide out.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6sapmodc/2/

**HTML**

```
<blue>
  <ul>
    <li>Colors
      <sub>Green</sub>
    </li>
    <li>Shapes
      <sub>Circle</sub>
    </li>
    <li>Sizes
      <sub>Large</sub>
    </li>
  </ul>
</blue>
```

**CSS**

```
blue {
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: initial;
}

blue ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 5;
}

blue ul li {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
}

blue ul li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

blue ul li sub {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: -4;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("li").click(function()
    {
        $("sub").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** For this point you have to use `$(this)` to reference the clicked `<li>` element and then use `find("sub")` to get the proper `<sub>` child.

**2) and 3)** are approaching detecting the current visible `<sub>` element, slide it out with `toggle("slide")` and then show the related `<sub>` of the clicked `<li>` element.

You can check next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("li").click(function()
   {
       var clickedSub = $(this).find("sub");

       // If there are no visible sub elements,
       // then just show the clicked one.
       
       if ($("sub:visible").length == 0 || clickedSub.is(":visible"))
       {
           clickedSub.toggle("slide");
           return;
       }
       
       // Otherwise, first hide the current visible element,
       // and then show the sub of the clicked element.
       
       $("sub:visible").toggle("slide").queue(function()
       {
           clickedSub.toggle("slide");
           $(this).dequeue();
       });
   });
 
});
```

```css
blue {
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: initial;
}
blue ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 5;
}
blue ul li {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
}
blue ul li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
blue ul li sub {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: -4;
    left: 180px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<blue>
    <ul>
        <li>Colors
          <sub>Green</sub>
        </li>
        <li>Shapes
          <sub>Circle</sub>
        </li>
        <li>Sizes
          <sub>Large</sub>
        </li>
    </ul>
</blue>
```

Comment: 2) doesn't work when the same tab is clicked to close it

Comment: @Gerard I have fixed that for you, check now.